# How to tell if bootstrap.js or bootstrap.bundle.js is loaded?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, popper.js

My code depends on both Bootstrap 4 and Popper.js. Bootstrap has a bundled JS file that includes Popper.js, but I can't figure out how to tell if the bundled or non-bundled version is loaded.

If bootstrap.js and popper.js are both included separately, I can test if `Popper` is defined, but if bootstrap.bundle.js is included `Popper` is not defined but the Bootstrap components that rely on Popper still work.

I can use something like `typeof $().modal` to check if bootstrap is included, but this is true of both the bundled and non-bundled verison.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap Bundle Test</title>
        <!-- Load jQuery JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <!-- Load Bootstrap Bundled JS -->
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-xrRywqdh3PHs8keKZN+8zzc5TX0GRTLCcmivcbNJWm2rs5C8PRhcEn3czEjhAO9o" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                console.log('jQuery type is: ' + typeof $);
                console.log('Bootstrap modal type is: ' + typeof $().modal);
                console.log('Popper type is: ' + typeof Popper);
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

In this example, I would expect `Popper` to be a function since it's included in the Bootstrap bundle, but it is `undefined`.

Comment: inside the bundle, Popper is defined as a private variable, so you can't reach it from the outside.

Comment: Don't you need to include the JS for popper separately? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#js

Comment: @RobertCooper - See this page for what's included with the bundled bootstrap JS file: [https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/contents/#js-files](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/contents/#js-files). And I'm interested in the JS code running on the page knowing whether Popper is included, not so much myself as a developer.

Comment: Ah ok, I understand. I think @dandavis is correct. Popper is private/protected and cannot by accessible outside the bundle: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/de1a6e3201a2f047c5abd2430795be32d37e9a35/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js#L6283

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check if a proper method available in global space. And if it's give you true it's then you know  bootstrap.js and popper.js are both included separately otherwise it's bootstrap.bundle.js